# Help removing excess starch from potato chips

Tags: potatoes, chips, starch

I was trying to make potato chips at home but forgot wash off the excess starch from the freshly cut potato slices. I have already dried them off. Now when i fry them they turn brown giving a burnt off kind of taste. What should I do???

Comment: Why not just soak them now?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Food Lab](http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/09/the-food-lab-extra-crunchy-homemade-potato-ch.html), the chemical that causes browning in homemade potato chips is *tyrosinase*. That article contains some really nice pictures to help demonstrate the value of soaking. Like this one:

[image]

Interestingly, after some experimentation, Kenji discovers a technique of first boiling the raw potato in a vinegar solution, drying, and then frying. According to him this gives the lightest coloration and cleanest taste.

I highly suggest checking out that article. In the meantime, I don't see why you couldn't simply re-soak your sliced potatoes now. You could even try out the par-boiling method indicated in the article if you are feeling adventurous. Unless your spuds have gone completely brown sitting on your cutting board you should be good to go.

Comment: Fascinating link.  I wonder if the chemistry of the vinegar solution is related to the brown coating that forms on pretzels after dipping into a lye or soda solution: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8249/why-should-i-boil-pretzels-in-baking-soda-water-before-baking