# Pre-making pretzel buns.

Tags: baking, pretzels

I've recently learned how to make my own pretzel buns, and was planning on using a similar technique to make pretzel dinner rolls for thanksgiving dinner next month.

The only problem is that I want to bake the buns at the house where they will be eaten, but I won't be able to boil them in the baking soda solution on site, as there will likely be no room on the range.

Will there be any problems with pre-boiling the pretzels and allowing them to sit, possibly overnight, before baking them?

Comment: [Room, room on the range...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_YK7ebcZ2o)

Comment: Allow them to cool down under a humid towel on your own range, wrap them individually in cling foil and keep them in the fridge overnight is what I would do...  To be tested though as I haven't tied that out. **;-)**

Comment: I was in a similar situation two weeks ago.  I made the dough, refrigerated overnight, then boiled and baked off the day of service.  I was not happy with the resulting texture of the pretzel.  I don't know if boiling before pausing overnight would have been better.  I have made decent pretzels without stopping the process for an overnight rest.  So, I do have a similar question; that is, what is the appropriate time to pause the pretzel making process...or, are they simply better when completed start to finish the same day.

Comment: You might want to read [this Q/A](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8249/why-should-i-boil-pretzels-in-baking-soda-water-before-baking), especially murmble's answer. The boiling is for interior *texture* (bagel-ish vs. fluffy rolls), the soda (or lye) for intensifying the maillard reaction and thus external *taste and colour*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to boil them in the baking soda solution on site then pre-boiling the pretzels shouldn't be a problem. I also agree with Fabby's comment above about wrapping them individually in a foil and keeping them refrigerated overnight. Note that I haven't tried this myself but am pretty confident that it should be fine, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are recipes where you can use room temperature baking soda rather than a boiling mixture. While it may not be exactly the same I've a recipe like that and they tasted great.